# MS Teams: Unable to get the SubEntityId value when a deep link is available in Activity Feed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am sending an activity Feed notification to the user which is pointing to my personal app.

I have a DeepLink generated to point to the tab and it's working fine but when I add a SubEntuityId to the tab it is not fetched in.

It is always blank.

I have also tried with URIEncode for the same.

Comment: can you paste a sample url here so we can see what it looks like

Comment: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<APPID>/overview?context={'subEntityId':  '949'}

Answer (score 0):

So presumably you're replacing APPID with the real app id from your manifest file. Separate to that, make sure that "overview" is registered as the actual entity id for the tab in the manifest. Other than that, the rest looks fine, like it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Hilton, I got my issue. The issue  is with the URIEncode, I am having the issue with the double quotes and single quotes. When I made that proper it worked

Comment: ok good, glad you got it working